# How to fix submit form call http method get with query params

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, httprequest

I have an asp net core mvc application. An action that create article. The problem is that when I submit the form , my application always calls the get method. How to fix this ?

- Create.cshtml

```
@model MyBlog.Models.Article

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Create article";
}

<h2>Create article</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Article", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div ass="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content,new { @id = "Content", @class = "form-control", @rows = "200" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <script>
                    CKEDITOR.replace("Content");
                </script> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

- Article controller:

```
// POST: Article
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind("Title,Content")] Article article)
        {
            try
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (DataException /* dex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
            }
            return View();
        }

        // GET: Article/Create
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

When I submit form. I see a url like this appears:

```
xxx//localhost:7158/article/create?Title=a&Content=b__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8JLgrvFS_U1JlinCQaKFM9rmomKaF5pDFJjX5Mbp7_OCoQq2hNZ6ygB05XZd-Qy8osia_h_1i1nzXuk5lZWQRBSTsId3hu-lbcapc3xDViukVhv6xeMv_ekiCyW6HdFkFh8iBzjXhJ9bRnZyrnP651U
```

- Debug on VS studio
  [image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue in my local, could you set breakpoint at line 35, I want to check whether it run into `return RedirectToAction("Index")` in your Create post Method.

Comment: I have found this bug. If I change Layout shared to null. It working. So I have modified my shared layout. Tks for your help ! @Jason Pan

Comment: You can summarize it as answer below, if someone face the same issue, it will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this bug. If I change Layout shared to null. It working. So I have modified my shared layout. Tks for your help !